# A/B test added elements in google optimize rendering twice (React/Nextjs app)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-optimize

My React/Next.js app contains some code in order to use Google Optimize.

All the optimize's debug shows that the experience is rendering correctly and when previewing the a/b test, it renders correctly.

Unfortunately when setting the test live, the elements that were added to the optimize's experience are rendering twice.

Here is my `_app.js` code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // // Google optimize workaround
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({ event: 'optimize.activate' });
    setLoaded(true);
}, []);
<Head>
                <title key="title">My Page </title>
                <link rel="preconnect" href="/www.google-analytics.com" crossOrigin />
                <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//www.google-analytics.com"></link>
                <script
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: `
                        (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
                            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
                            a = s.createElement(o),
                                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
                            a.async = 1;
                            a.src = g;
                            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
                        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
                        ga('create', 'GA_ID_OMITTED', 'auto');
                        ga('require', 'OPTIMISE_ID_OMITTED', {dataLayer: 'optimize.activate'});
                        ga('send', 'pageview');
                    `,
                    }}
                />
                <script sync src="https://www.googleoptimize.com/optimize.js?id=OPTIMISE_ID_OMITTED" />
            </Head>
```

Note: I have added had the optimize's script async with an anti-flickering code snippet and that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the issue for anyone that looks at this. It wasn't code related. Google Optimize requires you to delete previous changes to the html when editing the variants otherwise it will publish the same code the same amount of times you clicked editing and changes were created causing the elements to duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with anti flicker snippet, solved it  by putting the script inside a component and using a dynamic import to place the component inside . Although it does not work with next/script. It is probably happening because during server-side rendering (SSR), the component is rendered twice - once on the server and once on the client. This could lead to the script being inserted twice. You can also refer this: [A/B test added elements in google optimize rendering twice (React/Nextjs app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074639/a-b-test-added-elements-in-google-optimize-rendering-twice-react-nextjs-app)

```html
const AntiFlicker = () => {
  return (
    <>
     
      <script id="optimize-snippet">
        {`
          (function (a, s, y, n, c, h, i, d, e) {
            s.className += ' ' + y; h.start = 1 * new Date;
            h.end = i = function () { s.className =           s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?' + y), '') };
            (a[n] = a[n] || []).hide = h; setTimeout(function () { i(); h.end = null }, c); h.timeout = c;
            })(window, document.documentElement, 'async-     hide', 'dataLayer', 4000,{ '${process.env.GOOGLE_OPTIMIZE_ID}': true });
        `}
      </script>
    </>
  );
};

export default AntiFlicker;
```

inside _app.js

```html
const DynamicAntiFlicker = dynamic(() =>
  import('../utils/GoogleOptimize/AntiFlickerSnippet/index')
);
 
function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;
  return (
    <CacheProvider>
      <Head>
        <DynamicAntiFlicker />
        ...
      </Head>
```